# closed loop gain and bandwith calculation

Tags: operational-amplifier, bandwidth

[image]

For school I have to solve this schematic (For connection 7), but I have no idea how to do this.

They ask me to calculate the bandwith and the Closedloop gain in dB.

**Edit**: [High Resolution Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNhdq.jpg)

Comment: You could start by redrawing your circuit to include only the portions that are relevant when the switch is in position 7.  Then consider what you know about opamps already and reword the question to the specific portion you need assistance with.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fairly simple graphical method that can be used to solve this.  It's derived from the expression for the closed-loop gain for a negative feedback system:
$$
\text{Gain} = \frac{A}{1+AB}
$$
where *A* is the open-loop gain and *B* is the feedback factor. We can see from this that for large loop gain *AB*
$$
\text{Gain} \approx \frac{1}{B}
$$
In this example, *A* is the open-loop gain of the op amp. The feedback factor *B* is the feedback signal divided by the output signal with the input at zero, which in this case is
$$
B = \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_f}
$$
where \$R_f\$ is the equivalent resistance of the switched resistor network.  We have here \$R_1 = 10\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_f = 14.13\text{k}\Omega\$ for the switch in position 7. (The 1pF cap can be neglected.)

To use this method, plot \$|A| \text{ and } \frac{1}{B}\$ on a Bode plot:  The LF351 is dominant-pole compensated, so the plot of \$|A|\$ is a line sloping down at -20dB\decade and crossing zero dB at 4MHz, the gain-bandwidth product.  Since *B* = 0.4144, the plot of \$\frac{1}{B}\$ is a horizontal line at 7.65dB.

The frequency where these two lines cross is the closed-loop bandwidth.  In this case, they cross at 1.66MHz.  The \$\frac{1}{B}\$ line to the left of the bandwidth frequency and the \$|A|\$ line to the right are assymptotes of the closed loop frequency response curve.

This method is valid for inverting and non-inverting configurations, BUT for non-inverting, as in this case, the input signal "seen by" the summing point is attenuated by
$$
\frac{R_f}{R_1+R_f} = 1-B
$$
so the *overall* closed-loop gain is \$\frac{(1-B)}{B}\$ rather than \$\frac{1}{B}\$. This has the effect of shifting down the frequency response curve by \$20\text{ log}(1-B)\text{ dB}\$, which is -4.65dB in this case, so we have closed-loop gain = 3dB.